# Why do I see a "Leaving Facebook..." warning when I click on Messenger link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-send-api

My FB app sends links to users through the Send API inside a generic template. Most of the time, these links work fine, and Facebook opens the in-app browser and takes you directly to the web page. However, some links bring up the page below. Why is this happening for only some of the links? This link is about a month old. I've found it fairly difficult to get in touch with Facebook developer support, so thought I could get some help here.

Here is the image of the Facebook warning:
["Leaving Facebook" warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP2Yo.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The explanation why is part of what your screenshot shows already …

Comment: @CBroe the explanation doesn't make sense to me. I opened this up in my Messenger app, so of course I was logged in when it was sent to me. And I am logged into the same account when I click the link once again

Comment: _"I opened this up in my Messenger app, so of course I was logged in when it was sent to me"_ - that only means you are logged in in messenger. To open a link, it uses either a webview or the system browser - and in those you are probably not logged in to Facebook (cause they have no connection to the messenger's login.)

Comment: @CBroe in the case of webview, how was I able to log out? I'm unable to reproduce this warning error on iOS 10.1.1. There's not much opportunity to navigate or sign out of FB account within the webview

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to go to the Facebook site in the browser which showed the warning and to login to my Facebook account there.
After that this annoying message disappeared.